# How to make a stepper motor move at sinusoidal acceleration?

Tags: motor, stepper

I am new to arduino but I know basic concepts. How do I make the motor move at sinusoidal acceleration? I used the accelstepper library and it seems that at the end of each loop of distance with acceleration, the motor abruptly stops and begins accelerating again. Is there any way to stop this abrupt pause?

Comment: wow, you're doing this code line by line from answers here

Comment: Similar questions: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=557838.0 and https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=365301.0  Symplaz, is this for school? Please show us your sketch.